# do I have to delete Civicrm folder before upgrade - cant I just rename?

Tags: upgrade

Cant I just rename it ?
It would make the restore process quicker if the upgrade fails.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be one of the below

1. Tar/zip the current civi folder and delete.
2. Move the current civi folder out of the cms directory.

Comment: Just to add to this answer: my understanding is that the CMS will search for executable code in certain folders,, and run whatever is there. If there are two copies it could try to run both and create conflicts.